# Div as "WebParts" positioning

Tags: css

I am little bit lost in CSS now. Here is the thing:

I have a website with many "webparts" (standalone div containers) with diferent heights and I want to that webparts fit all empty spaces. It will be pretty easy, but here is the catch. I have three columns, but if users resolution is less than 1440px width, page display context only two columns.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1440px) {
.floatdiv {
width: 33.3%; }}

.floatdiv {
width:50%;
float:left;
```

And here is HTML:

```
<div style="margin-right;60px;">
  <div class="floatdiv">Some text here</div>
  <div class="floatdiv">Some text here</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Thank you for your ideas.

It looks like:

[now](http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=badmjm.jpg)

and I want something like this:

[wish](http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=goodgcg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column-count CSS property describes the number of columns of the element.

**Initial value** :auto

**Applies to**: non-replaced block elements (except table elements), table-cell or inline-block elements

**Inherited**: no

**Media**: visual

**Computed value** :as specified

**Animatable** : yes, as an integer

**Canonical order** :the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar

### Syntax

```
column-count: 3;
column-count: auto;
```

### Solution

```css
#Container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding:2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.floatdiv {
    border: 2px solid #bb8ed8;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
     background:#d77575;

}
```

```html
<div id="Container" class="cols">
    <div class="floatdiv">Some t ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, here</div>
    <div class="floatdiv">Some t ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, here</div>
    <div class="floatdiv">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <div class="floatdiv">Some t ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, here</div>
    <div class="floatdiv">Some t ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, here</div>
    <div class="floatdiv">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It wasfloat:left; popularised in the 1960s with the releas</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at masonry layout: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/

There are plenty things to find on the internet, but you could start taking a look at here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this without javascript, but your answer is very interesting aproach.